# How can I set up bootchart in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, bootchart

[This page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting) says that I have to  edit the "linux" line in the grub boot menu to set up bootchart. I do not understand what exactly it is that I have to do. Please help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to do that any more in 15.10 or any other Ubuntu release booting with `systemd`. It automatically records the necessary information on every boot and allows you to analyse it with the command

```
systemd-analyze
```

The argument to get a graphical bootchart as SVG image is:

```
systemd-analyze plot > filename.svg
```

[image: screenshot]

But it has also other useful commands. You see a list of possible arguments by entering `systemd-analyze` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice using the Bash autocompletion, or old-style by opening the manual page with `man systemd-analyze` or showing the help with `systemd-analyze --help`.
Here's a list of the commands. Default is `time`, if you don't specify any other:

```
Commands:
  time                    Print time spent in the kernel
  blame                   Print list of running units ordered by time to init
  critical-chain          Print a tree of the time critical chain of units
  plot                    Output SVG graphic showing service initialization
  dot                     Output dependency graph in dot(1) format
  set-log-level LEVEL     Set logging threshold for systemd
  dump                    Output state serialization of service manager
  verify FILE...          Check unit files for correctness
```

Comment: systemd-analyze plot is different from bootchart. Bootchart gives a different in some ways more complex plot about the boot.