# Average of CPU and memory use of ALL process that appear during some time interval

Tags: 18.04, cpu, process, cat, htop

I know some ways that I can see the average of CPU and memory use for one process, but I never saw a way to see the average of all process that appeared during some time.

The goal is, for example, to see what process, since the moment I turned on my laptop, is consuming most CPU and memory. If I see just one process at a time I'll never get this, because I need to compare a process with the other processes.

Answer (score 1):

```
systemd-analyze plot > filename.svg
```

[image: screenshot]

Borrowed from another [relevant answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710127/how-can-i-set-up-bootchart-in-ubuntu-15-10)